(PyTket) Trouble with RoutingPass.apply() running forever -- seems to hang
I am attempting to route a circuit with 3 qubits, each connected via a 2 qubit gate that is defined using the Unitary2qBox. This sequence is repeated several times. So there are 3 choose 2 gates or 3 gates. When I attempt to route this, the RoutingPass function never seems to end. When I manually try to use a MappingManager, each algorithm in the documentation says they're invalid. Any ideas? The Architecture is simply a loop defined using tuples.

Hi, welcome to QCSE. I think I can help with this. Could you share the code with what you’ve attempted so far?

Unfortunately this does seem like a bug. Now being dealt with here -> https://github.com/CQCL/tket/issues/1463
